# When doing multiple jobs in a pipeline Jenkinsfile, how do I capture the logs for the given build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

As the title states, I want to capture the logs for all the stages in my build, which looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build First Repo') {
            steps {
                build job: 'jobOne', parameters: [string(name: 'branch', value: "${params.branch}")], quietPeriod: 1
            }
        }
        stage ('Build Second Repo') {
            steps {         
                build job: 'jobTwo', parameters: [string(name: 'branch', value: "${params.someOtherBranch}")], quietPeriod: 1
            }
        }
        stage ('Deploy') {
            steps {
                build job: 'jobThree', parameters: [string(name: 'buildEnvironment', value: "${params.environment}")], quietPeriod: 1
            }   
        }
        stage ('Remote Build') {
            steps {
                build job: 'jobFour', parameters: [string(name: 'Hosts', value: "${params.hosts}")], quietPeriod: 1
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            mail to:me@mydomain.com, subject: "${currentBuild.currentResult} - ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", body:"...${currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(100)}"
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I can only get the *pipeline* build log (which I am e-mailing in the post/always section), which is helpful but not sufficient; I'd like to get the logs from each of the stages.  I thought of maybe capturing them per stage and creating an environment variable or something but I'm not sure how to even access the logs for the build of those jobs.  Can someone point me in the right direction on how to capture the logs for those jobs?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a post section after an any stage.
And you can setup sendind emails there.
To send single email from the build you can use stash/unstash command. You can stash log at each section and finally unstash them and send an email.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a good approach.  However I'm still unclear on the core of the issue, which is how to access the logs from the build job steps.

Comment: What are you mean by the logs from the build job steps? Generally, the build has no own log. Only the log you create is stored.

Comment: Every build has a log file, which is accessed like this: `${currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(100)}`.  However, each build job in the above pipeline has *their own* logs inside the individual jobs that are kicked off.  My question is if it is possible to reference them from this pipeline script.